# unable to locate cause of infinite loop in JavaScript program

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, infinite

I am writing a program for fun and practice that takes a user input and guesses the input value. I can't take a prompt however in my testing environment, so I use the number 5 instead, and I also use debug instead of console.log. I cannot find the location of where the infinite loop starts, as far as I can tell it just counts up an array until it gets to the string '5', and the loop should be stopped. I need a second pair of eyes on this one, Stack Overflow. Thanks!

```
//Password Cracker

//"userPassword" will not be read by the computer, instead it will be guessed and reguessed.
var userPassword = 5 + ''

//the following variable contains an array of all the possible characters that can be present.
var possibleCharacters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'];

//the computer's current guess.
var computerGuess = null;

//establishes that the computer has not correctly guessed the password, will be changed when password is discovered.
var correctGuess = null;

//the following variable keeps track of how many guesses it takes for the computer to crack the password.
var totalGuesses = 0;

//the following function checks if the current guess of the computer matches the password inputted by the user.
var checkPassword = function(passwordGuess) {

    if(passwordGuess === userPassword) {
        debug("Your password is " + computerGuess + ". Gotta do better to fool me!");
    }else{
        debug("Guessing again.");
    };

};

//the loop that should stop when the password has been guessed correctly. the variable 'i' counts up through the strings in the array.
while(computerGuess !== userPassword) {

    for(var i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
        computerGuess = possibleCharacters[i];
        checkPassword(computerGuess);
        };
    };

end;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code directly. Anyway, your for loop doesn't stop when it gets to the right pass character, so then when the for ends the while loop condition is still true. Why do you even have nested loops when the pass "word" can only be one character?

Comment: in each while loop, you're looping through ALL 61 (shouldn't it be 62?) possibilities in the for loop ... at the end, computerGuess will be the 61st possibility ('9') when the while loop checks if it's found ... so, it will never be found .. you need to stop the for loop - in fact, you don't even need a while loop... if you set the password to '9' and I bet it wont infinitely loop

Comment: also `var userPassword = 5 + ''` could be better written `var userPassword = '5'`

Comment: @Ageonix - that is valid JS.

Comment: Unlikely to be the issue, but what is `end;`?

Comment: Additionally, all you have here is an overly unclear implementation of a linear search. You might want to look into the [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method to simplify your code, and reduce the chance of error.

Comment: @Oka, seems somewhere before defined `end` variable :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//the loop that should stop when the password has been guessed correctly. the variable 'i' counts up through the strings in the array.
while(computerGuess !== userPassword) {    
    for(var i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
        computerGuess = possibleCharacters[i];
        checkPassword(computerGuess);
    };
};
```

This is an infinite loop since the inner loop (the `for` loop) always iterates through all characters, so computerGuess is `'0'` at the end. Therefore, the while condition is always satisfied. You could solve that by breaking the for loop once you have guessed the right password:

```
while(computerGuess !== userPassword) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 61 && computerGuess !== userPassword; i++) {
        computerGuess = possibleCharacters[i];
        checkPassword(computerGuess);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bruteforce attack check out this algorithm here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68063/brute-force-password-cracker

or google some "bruteforce javascript algorithm"

Cheers

Comment: How does this relate to the OP's problem with the infinite loop?

Comment: I'm not really making this to crack any passwords, just as a fun challenge

Comment: It looks like a passwortcracker but you say it isn't. So it is not a Passwordcracker?

Comment: In Russia they say: If boss says rabbit is a bird, the rabbit is a f... bird

Comment: Even though your code is just wrong to crack the password so solving the infinite loop won't solve your problem. I was just thinking a bit ahead down the road. Sorry for that. You need a function which adds more characters after you tried single characters and so on. Best would be a function which calls itself again and again until you have the result. Otherwise you always check one letter against the whole user password.